# is there a way to run a JQuery function even the DOMs are not yet loaded

Tags: jquery

im thinking if there is a way to run a jquery function like $.post even if the DOM's are not yet loaded..

Comment: I was just about to ask that. 0.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you place your script after jQuery has been loaded, you are free to execute any jQuery functions. However, DOM manipulation will, of course, be unreliable if you're outside of a `$(document).ready()` block or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, once jquery has loaded.

```
function checkJquery(){
    if(typeof($)==undefined){
        setTimeout(checkJquery,500);
    } else {
        start();
    }
}
setTimeout(checkJquery,500);
```

Then write your code in `start()`.

Comment: Scripts are executed in a single thread in sequential order according to the placement in the markup. So, if your script is placed after jQuery has been executed, jQuery is available.

Comment: I was going to answer the same thing, but thought that the situation was complexer, like OP was loading jQuery dynamically or something in the fashion.